# How to use FieldValue.serverTimestamp in application models

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my Typescript application code I define a model which uses a timestamp generated on the server by Firestore. When the document returns from the database this field will be an ISO string. I want to use the same model definition throughout my app for both writing and reading data, but this poses a problem.

I would typically write something like this:

```
interface Document {
  title: string,
  createdAt: string
}

async function addDocument(document: Document): Promise<string> {
  const id = await firestore.collection('documents').add(someDocument)
  return id
}

async function getDocumentData(documentId: string): Promise<Document> {
  const doc = await firestore.collection('documents').doc(documentId).get()

  invariant(doc.exists, `No document available with id ${documentId}`)
  return doc.data() as Document
}

const someDocument: Document = {
  title: "How to",
  createdAt: firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
}

const newDocumentId = await addDocument(someDocument)
```

Now the Typescript compiler is complaining that the value for `someDocument` is not compatible, because `createdAt` is defined as a string.

Before, I hacked around this by tricking the compiler into believing it is a string with `createdAt: firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() as string`.

With a recent update to Typescript this tolerance seems to have disappeared with the strict settings that I'm using. The compiler is now telling me:

> Type 'FieldValue' cannot be converted to type 'string'.

In stead of working around the compiler again, I'm wondering what would be the correct way to handle this?

-- edit --

Looking at this again because of the upcoming change in Firestore timestamp behaviour I discovered that the API didn't actually return ISO strings but Date object. Because Date objects have automatic string conversion my code always worked, but the type definitions were incorrect in that sense. This doesn't change much to my initial question though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The new behavior for Firebase will be to return the `Timestamp` object from the db methods, instead of a Date object.

In my type definitions file I now import the Timestamp type (you need Typescript 2.9 for this) and then use it in my models like this:

```
export type FirestoreTimestamp = import("firebase").firestore.Timestamp;

export interface LockableItem {
  isLocked: boolean;
  lockedBy?: UserId;
  lockedAt?: FirestoreTimestamp;
}
```

When setting the lockedAt field with a FieldValue you can now simply do this:

```
const item: LockableItem = { 
  isLocked: true,
  lockedAt: FieldValue.serverTimestamp() as FirestoreTimestamp, 
  lockedBy: "someuser" 
}
```

Comment: `FieldValue.serverTimestamp() as FirestoreTimestamp` is the solution I had, though it feels a bit hacky. The alternative would be to have incoming and outgoing models (perhaps specified by a generic somehow?) and having lockedAt be a FieldValue in outgoing, but Timestamp in incoming.

Comment: @Nathan I think it's not a smart API design to use Type Assertions here because it effectively bypasses type checking. Shouldn't `serverTimestamp()` return the appropriate type instead of `FieldValue`? That seems like a cleaner solution.

Comment: When using the DTO (when you create the document), the data type doesn't match the type in the document (when you get the document). How did you resolve this discrepancy?

Comment: I've since solved this all. Firebase SDK exposes a `WithFieldValue` type that you can wrap types with, and all the write methods expect it. It recursively decorates each field with a union of itself and a FieldValue. As for reading, I use a generic converter (.withConverter) that converts timestamps to the Date objects that my models expect.

Comment: Yes, the new WithFieldValue is what we needed. And I haven't tried withConverter yet, but that seems to be the right way to map things indeed.

If you are willing to write it as an answer, I will accept that as the solution of course.